# What is the jQuery equivalent to offsetHeight?

Tags: jquery

What is the jQuery equivalent of `offsetHeight` in JavaScript?

I want to translate the following code to use JQuery

```
document.querySelector('.site-header').offsetHeight;
```

Answer (score 46):

The [`offsetHeight` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) includes the vertical padding and borders in the height calculation, therefore the [`.outerHeight()` method](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) would be the jQuery equivalent.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ot68Lz4t/)

```
$('.site-header').outerHeight();
```

As a side note, the [`.outerHeight()` method](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) takes an optional parameter to include the vertical margin(s) in the height calculation:

```
$('.site-header').outerHeight(true); // With vertical margins included.
```

Comment: It's really important to note here that while this is _roughly equivalent_, it is not quite the same.  This is because the DOM API  [`HTMLElement.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/offsetHeight) will always return an **integer**, unlike jQuery's `.outerHeight()` method which will not be rounded to the nearest integer. This is important if you're comparing this to [`HTMLElement.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/scrollHeight) which **also** always returns an integer.

Comment: @chunk_split - keep in mind, I wrote my answer 5+ years ago - good catch regarding the integer/rounding issue. Which jQuery version are you referring to?

Comment: Totally get it! The version of jQuery I'm referring to specifically is 3.3.1 (so relatively new as of writing this). Based on their current documentation, they say it returns a `Number` (which is accurate) and that was [still the case in 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150115085245/https://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) but [going back to 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101207070738/https://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) they definitely *used* to at least document it as returning an Integer, interestingly enough. Even then -- it's still easy to miss if you rely on it!

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's [`.outerHeight()`](https://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) method is *similar* but it's not exactly the same, since it doesn't always return an **integer** like [`HTMLElement.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/offsetHeight) does.

The *most precise* way to translate the example above would actually be to swap out the selection of the element and just leave `offsetHeight` in place:

```js
$('.site-header')[0].offsetHeight;
```

Or, to keep it pure jQuery and maintain the integer result:

```
Math.round($('.site-header').outerHeight());
```

It turns out this is important when comparing the output with other properties like  [`HTMLElement.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/scrollHeight) which will also always returns an integer.

**Why it matters:** I hit this snag myself when doing code review. I thought they were equivalent, but couldn't understand why this wasn't working on my machine, but yet it *was* working on the other developer's machine:

```js
// My machine: 149.714 < 150 = true
// Other machine: 150 < 150 = false
let lessTall = $container.outerHeight() < $container.prop('scrollHeight')
```

I believe this was due to the varying device pixel ratios (he was on a Macbook and I was on Windows 10 with 4k displays). The general solution here was to ensure that we're performing the same type of computations evenly on both sides when doing comparisons; i.e. round numbers on both sides instead of just one side or, in our case, just use the same API on both sides for internal consistency. For example, my solution was:

```js
// My machine: 150 < 150 = false
// Other machine: 150 < 150 = false
let lessTall = container.offsetHeight < container.scrollHeight;
```