# Is there any way to get offsetheight of an element by its Class Name

Tags: jquery, html

As [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetheight.asp) suggests, we can use Id to get offsetheight. Is there anyway it can be achieved by using a class name??

```js
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("myId");
    alert("Offset height : "+ elmnt.offsetHeight);
})

$("#btn1").click(function(){
    var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
    alert("Offset height : "+ elmnt.offsetHeight);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myId" class="myClass">Lorem Ipsum!</div>

<button id="btn1">Ofset height using Class Name</button>

<button id="btn2">Ofset height using Id</button>
```

This is not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method), Because I want to know how to select OffsetHeight with class and the answer to this question clears that

Comment: If you're using jQuery, rather than `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`, you'd typically use `$()`. But in any case, see the linked question's answers for why your code above doesn't work.

Comment: [What is the jQuery equivalent to offsetHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079032/what-is-the-jquery-equivalent-to-offsetheight)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` will return collection of element. You need to find first element in matched set and then use offsetHeight property on it:

```
var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
```

```js
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("myId");
    console.log("Offset height : "+ elmnt.offsetHeight);
})

$("#btn1").click(function(){
    var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
    console.log("Offset height : "+ elmnt.offsetHeight);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myId" class="myClass">Lorem Ipsum!</div>

<button id="btn1">Ofset height using Class Name</button>

<button id="btn2">Ofset height using Id</button>
```